# How to log in into the linux terminal as ROOT user using ruby script

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, su

I want to run a script on remote server using SSH.

I have write all the code which runs properly using system command.

To run my code on remote server I need some packages which I need to install on remote server.

To do so I need login into remote terminal as a ROOT user. When I try to do using Ruby script so I get something like following

```
[not_root_user@remote_server]$ su
Password:
```

I need some command using which I can able to login into the remote server something like following

```
[not_root_user@remote_server]$ su -p ******
[root@remote_server]#
```

Is there any linux command which accepts the password in it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want your script to act as root?

It's not really recommended, but you can use expect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

The wiki there has a walkthrough for a basic automated telnet session that you could adapt to your needs.

However, you're going to have your root password in plain text, which could be a security issue. If you go that route, I'd definitely obliterate all copies of that script from the universe once this package is installed.

But if you're allowing direct root logins, you've already got a bit of a security problem. Sudo works out-of-the-box on every modern linux distro I've used, I'd stick with that, if possible.

Another option which is equally tasteless would be to set up root-to-root login without a password via ssh.

Comment: I'm not sure that you could use `expect` to script `su` - I believe it uses some magic to make sure it gets it's input from a tty, and not `stdin`.

Comment: you'd launch the expect script on the local system, I'm sure I've done it, in a lab, at least, 5 or 6 years ago, lol.

Comment: Yes, but the asker mentions using the `system` call to run commands on the remote system, so I assume his script runs there.

Comment: in either case, it works. if he launches the expect script from the local system and the target script on the remote system, it will run, or if he launches the expect script on the remote system, it will run. I just ran through a test on Linux HFC-2600 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux and it works as expected. Brings you into the login shell, runs commands, exits.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo would be my first option to getting around this. Although not the best option.

You can also use Key authentication with SSH, and if password authentication is turned off there is no need to enter a password.